# How to sort userlist on the basis of number of likes or age?

Tags: 7

How to sort userlist on the basis of number of likes(eg:by flag module) or age(taxonomy term) having each user.

For this i have created a view of users, i want to show **sort** by **likes and age** the result page should sort on the basis of assending and desending order .

How to acheive this functionality?

Comment: i followed this link https://eureka.ykyuen.info/2011/07/28/drupal-add-sorting-to-view/ but i am not getting which value i have to pass in $query->orderby[0]='term_data.name ASC';

Comment: Why are you looking into a semi-coding solution?

Comment: Going off memory here, but for the age(tax term) you can do it by adding a SORT of Taxonomy Term Weight. It will sort it based on the order of your tax terms, so assuming your age terms are in order, this should work.

Comment: For the flag, try adding a RELATIONSHIP of flag count, then add a SORT for that.

Comment: u r not getting my point i have to show dynamic drop down on the view display when user select sort by age or like ,the result display should sort on the basis of selected dropdown in asc or desc direction

Comment: Expose the filter and use a group filter.